# How to destroy javascript array reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

If I create an array, and an object. Then assign the object to an index of the array. I can edit the properties of the object without touching the array and If I try to accesses it through the array the updated properties are reflected.

I then want to delete the object and have the array clear those indices. I hoped I could do this by setting it to null. Dosen't seem to be the case. Heres simplified nodejs console output below

```
> var ar = [[],[]]
undefined
> var cool = {story: "bro"};
undefined
> ar[0][20] = cool
{ story: 'bro' }
> cool.story = "gurl"
'gurl'
> ar[0][20]
{ story: 'gurl' }
> cool = null
null
> ar[0][20]
{ story: 'gurl' }
```

Comment: You cannot. JS is a garbage-collected language; you will need to nullifiy all references to an object to get rid of it. Do `arr[0][20] = null`

Comment: With objects and arrays you do indeed assign a reference pointer in JS

Comment: I just learned something. This cleared it up for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318357/javascript-pointer-reference-craziness-can-someone-explain-this