# Sequelize update change the pre-initialized variable

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I am trying to save a sequelize instance into a variable before update. But after updating, the old variable is also updated into the new sequelize instance, which makes the .description of the variable 'oldRequest' before and after different.

```
var oldRequest = request; // HUGE BUG HERE, OLD REQUEST IS ALSO MODIFIED AS REQUEST IS MODIFIED
        console.log("before " + oldRequest.description);
        attributes.lastUpdater = req.user.get('firstName') + " " + req.user.get('lastName');
        request.update(attributes).then(function(updatedRequest) {
            console.log("after " + oldRequest.description);
            send_update_email(oldRequest ,updatedRequest, req.user.get('email')).then(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `oldRequest` is really just referencing the same object `request`. See this question for an in depth explaination: [Javascript pointer/reference craziness. Can someone explain this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318357/javascript-pointer-reference-craziness-can-someone-explain-this)

If you need to save off the `description` try something like this, using a clone: (See this answer for details: [Cloning an Object in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055746/cloning-an-object-in-node-js))

```
var extend = require('util')._extend;
var oldRequest = extend({}, request);
...
```