# Javascript assigning a new object to a function prototype, removes the link between the instance and the function prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
function User() {
  this.name = "name";
}

User.prototype.age = 10;

const user1 = new User(); // user1 -> { name: "name" }

console.log(user1.age) // prints 10
console.log(user1.__proto__ === user.prototype) // prints true

// if i change the age value on prototype, then user1.age will return the new value
User.prototype.age = 20;
console.log(user1.age) // prints 20
```

The above code works as expected, because when i call "User" function with keyword `new` it will return an object that only has `name` property and that object will be linked to `User.prototype`.

But What i don't get is when I've assigned the prototype with an object, there's no link anymore.

```
User.prototype = {age: 30};

console.log(user1.age) // prints 20! , Why?, shouldn't it print 30?
console.log(user1.__proto__ === User.prototype) // prints false
```

P.S: even if the link is lost because the reference of User.porotype has been changed, but why `user1.age` is still returning `20` not `undefined`

Edit: As the answers have mentioned, this has nothing to do with `prototype`, I've got confused because i was thinking that the object reference is like a pointer which is not. Which was already answered here [Javascript pointer/reference craziness. Can someone explain this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318357/javascript-pointer-reference-craziness-can-someone-explain-this)

Comment: Well, you’ve replaced the object. The class’ `prototype` and the instance’s `__proto__` are now two different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you declare `const user1 = new User();`, behind the scene you will get `user1.__proto__ = User.prototype`.

Reassigning `User.prototype` later to another object will not affect `user1.__proto__`, the value will remain the same as before, it will keep a reference to the original prototype object.

In fact, it has nothing to do with the `prototype` thing, it's just related to object affectation like in the following example :

```js
let obj1 = {a: 2};
const obj2 = obj1;
obj1 = {b: 2}
   
console.log(obj2); // print {a: 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you reassign the `.prototype` property, old instances which used to have their internal prototype point to the old prototype *do not get changed*. See the docs on [`setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf):

> Warning: Changing the [[Prototype]] of an object is, by the nature of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, currently a very slow operation in every browser and JavaScript engine. In addition, the effects of altering inheritance are subtle and far-flung, and are not limited to simply the time spent in the Object.setPrototypeOf(...) statement, but may extend to any code that has access to any object whose [[Prototype]] has been altered.

If old instances had their prototypes automatically updated, it would be a very expensive operation, and could cause odd breakages. Assigning a new object to the `.prototype` will only affect *new* instances.

If you want to update the prototypes of existing instances, you'd have to do it manually (for informational purposes only - it's a very strange thing to want to do in the first place)

```js
function User() {
}
const user1 = new User();
User.prototype = { age: 30 };
Object.setPrototypeOf(user1, User.prototype);

console.log(user1.age)
console.log(user1.__proto__ === User.prototype)
```